# Using Gorm getting undefined: mysql.Open

Tags: go, mysql-connector

reviewed the docs for gorm, and I think I am following the pattern correctly. I have run go build and go mod tidy.

but still the same error persists.

package main

```
import (
    "encoding/json"
    "github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql"
    "gorm.io/gorm"
    "net/http"
)

var DB *gorm.DB
var err error

const DNS = "root:654321cg@tcp(127.0.0.1:3306)/resourcesdb?charset=utf8&parseTime=True&loc=Local"

...

func InitialMigration()  {
    DB, err = gorm.Open(mysql.Open(DNS), &gorm.Config{})
    if err != nil {
        println(err.Error())
        panic("Cannot connect to DB")
    }
    DB.AutoMigrate(&Client{})
}



func createClient(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json")
    var client Client
    json.NewDecoder(r.Body).Decode(&client)
    DB.Create(&client)
    json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(client)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remplace `"github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql"` with `"gorm.io/driver/mysql"`

```
import (
    "encoding/json"
    "gorm.io/driver/mysql"
    "gorm.io/gorm"
    "net/http"
)

var DB *gorm.DB
var err error

const DNS = "root:654321cg@tcp(127.0.0.1:3306)/resourcesdb?charset=utf8&parseTime=True&loc=Local"

...

func InitialMigration()  {
    DB, err = gorm.Open(mysql.Open(DNS), &gorm.Config{})
    if err != nil {
        panic("Cannot connect to DB")
    }
    DB.AutoMigrate(&Client{})
}



func createClient(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json")
    var client Client
    json.NewDecoder(r.Body).Decode(&client)
    DB.Create(&client)
    json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(client)
}
```

Comment: how is this different from what OP answered 3 hours ago?

Answer (score 0):

figured this out. imported the wrong pkg.

substituting

```
"gorm.io/driver/mysql"
```

instead of

```
"github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql"
```

fixes it.